# Page navigation click without using current_url python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, click

How to navigate through each page without using driver.current_url? In my full code, I get a bunch of errors once I navigate through the page for a loop. Without it, it runs fine but can only go through one page. I want to navigate through as many pages. Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
driver.maximize_window()  # load web driver
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

url_test = driver.get('https://www.seek.com.au/data-jobs-in-information-communication-technology/in-All-Perth-WA')
url_template = driver.current_url
template = url_template+ '?page={}'
for page in range(2,5):
    link_job = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-automation='jobTitle']")]
    for job in link_job:
        driver.get(job)
        try:
            quick_apply = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@data-automation='job-detail-apply' and @target='_self'])")))
            quick_apply.click()
            #sleep(3)
        except:
            print("No records found " + job)
            pass
        sleep(3)
    driver.get(template.format(page))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to determine dynamically how many pages there are and loop over each of them.
I have managed to achieve this by using a while loop and look on each page if the "Next" button at the bottom is visible. If not, the last page was reached and you can exit the loop.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from time import sleep

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Stefan\\bin\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)
driver.maximize_window()  # load web driver
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

url_test = driver.get('https://www.seek.com.au/data-jobs-in-information-communication-technology/in-All-Perth-WA')
url_template = driver.current_url
template = url_template+ '?page={}'
page = 1
while True:

    # check if "Next" button is visible 
    # -> if not, the last page was reached
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Next']")
    except:
        # last page reached
        break
    
    link_job = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-automation='jobTitle']")]
    for job in link_job:
        driver.get(job)
        try:
            quick_apply = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@data-automation='job-detail-apply' and @target='_self'])")))
            quick_apply.click()
            #sleep(3)
        except:
            print("No records found " + job)
            pass
        sleep(3)
    page += 1
    driver.get(template.format(page))

driver.close()
```

Comment: Not really, in the full code I'll just specify how many pages I want to manually. The issue is that I don't want to use driver.current url and format it to a template to loop through. In the full code there's issues that come with it and I'm trying to work around that. This might work, I'll test around a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your problem is with `StaleElementException` when you getting back from job page to jobs search results page.
The simplest approach to overcome this problem is to keep the jobs search results page url.
Actually I changed your code only with this point and it works.
I also changed `driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@data-automation='jobTitle']")` with `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-automation='jobTitle']")))` for better performance.
The code below works, but the web site itself responds badly.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")


webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
url = 'https://www.seek.com.au/data-jobs-in-information-communication-technology/in-All-Perth-WA?page={p}'
for p in range(1,20):
    driver.get(url)
    link_job = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@data-automation='jobTitle']")))]
    for job in link_job:
        driver.get(job)
        try:
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@data-automation='job-detail-apply' and @target='_self'])"))).click()
            print("applied")
        except:
            print("No records found " + job)
            pass
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: It's pretty much that, but I want to do it without a url string. In the full code, I search for the term instead of just grabbing it so there's nothing to loop through if you know what I mean. There won't be a url = 'url_string' in my full code.